# copy function in batch script does not work

Tags: batch-file

I am writing a batch script where I am writing a set of instruction inside function as I want to call it many time so want to reuse it.For me it works when i write outside function but inside function it never works . Below the code  which I have used .

```
@echo off

set _prefs="%APPDATA%\test\test\BrowserProfile\prefs.js"
set _prefs_notes="%ProgramFiles(x86)%\test\tset1\Data\workspace\BrowserProfile\prefs.js"

#rem it works
copy /y %_prefs_notes% %_prefs_notes%.copy1 > nul

CALL :AMEND_PREFJS %_prefs_notes%
EXIT /B 




:AMEND_PREFJS
rem make copy of prefs file
#rem it does not work
copy /y %~1 %~1.copy > nul
findstr /v "layers.acceleration.disabled" "%~1" > "%~1.tmp"
echo end

set %~1=
EXIT /B 0
goto end

:prefs_not_found
rem set error level?
echo "file does not exist -- %_prefs_notes%"

:end
set _prefs=
```

Comment: I doubt your first `COPY` command works.  The `X86` directory has spaces in the folder name.  So your `CALL` to your function will not work because of that as well. You need to put quotes around file paths with spaces.

Comment: sorry I forgot the quotes while trying to play with it .It works with quotes

Comment: So if you turn `ECHO ON` and run the batch file from the command prompt instead of running it with your mouse, what error do you get? I know what your problem is, I am just teaching you to troubleshoot.  I will give you a hint.  What does your `findstr` command have that your `copy` command does not?

Comment: Well there is no error i donot see any error only the copy does not get created

Comment: find str throws error though

Comment: There are other flaws, you can't do this `set %~1=` (at best it has no effect or you get errors). In general you should set variables with double quotes around like this `set "var=value"` and double quotes when using. I.e.: `copy /y "%_prefs_notes%" "%_prefs_notes%.copy1" > nul`

Comment: Thanks Squashman It works I could able to figure out

Comment: So you understand now what the `~` does? The `copy` command was definitely throwing an error because of it.

Comment: yup thanks by the way .and sorry for a silly question

Comment: You can put your answer .If you want I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to tell you what most of us do as best practices for writing batch files.

Never assign quotes to variables. You can use quotes though to protect the **assignment** of the variable. This helps with protecting special characters within the assignment and also keeps you from assigning trailing spaces.

Get into the habit of always using quotes to surround your file paths when using them with another command.

This is how I would write your batch file.

```
@echo off

set "_prefs=%APPDATA%\test\test\BrowserProfile\prefs.js"
set "_prefs_notes=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\test\tset1\Data\workspace\BrowserProfile\prefs.js"

#rem it works
copy /y "%_prefs_notes%" "%_prefs_notes%.copy1" > nul

CALL :AMEND_PREFJS "%_prefs_notes%"
EXIT /B 

:AMEND_PREFJS
rem make copy of prefs file
#rem it does not work
copy /y "%~1" "%~1.copy" > nul
findstr /v "layers.acceleration.disabled" "%~1" > "%~1.tmp"
echo end
EXIT /B 0
```

Comment: Thanks My btch script worked now and  I learnt a new thing too